# jQuery select a specific element of an element class with variable as the selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html, for-loop

I want to add a class to a specific element of an element array, but I want to add it based on a variable of the for loop, not just a random number, and add it to more than one elements if I have to, but the point is, I need to search the elements with the variable given to me!

```
for(var a = 0; a < array.length; a++){    
  $('.results').append('some html divs here');
  if(array[a].id == $.cookie('userId')){
    $('.buyButton').addClass('disabled'); // here's my problem I don't want to add the
//disabled class to every element with the buyButton class, but just the one selected by the if statement
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify precisely what you're asking? What's the desired behaviour, and what's happening currently?

Comment: @Utkanos The disabled function is added to every .buyButton element. I want it to be added to only the ones that have the array[a].id equal to the cookie (hence the "if" statement!)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your array is an array of divs, if so you can use your array rather then the class as your jQuery object to alter the class, as so

```
for(var a = 0; a < array.length; a++){    
 $('.results').append('some html divs here');
  if(array[a].id == $.cookie('userId')){
  array[a].addClass('disabled');
 }
}
```

Comment: The array is actually an array of objects (from the db), and in json format!

Comment: What is your mechanism then of linking each objects property to a specific buy button? Can you populate an id, value, or dummy class field of the buttons to compare to your array of objects?

Comment: A find function searches the database for what is asked. Then, socket.io sends it to the client. Jquery then, sets up the html. The id of each element found in the database, is set by the $('.results').append() function, which runs in the "for" loop and then there's the $('.buyButton').addClass('disabled'); function that I want to be triggered only for the element, the "for" loop is currently at!

Comment: Okay, sounds like a good data flow. I'm likely not seeing the whole problem but if you make ,  $('.results').append('some html divs here') a variable at each iteration of your for loop, such as var check =  $('.results').append('some html divs here'), then you could compare check.find('.buyButton').